# Cannot locate a specific file path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a flutter package "BiblePlus". This package will read a `.pdb` file but when I specified a path to my `.pdb` file which is inside the lib folder (lib/pdb) I get this error:

> Cannot open file, path = '/pdb/KJVD.pdb' (OS Error: No such file or
> directory, errno = 2)

Please refer to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn4GB.png) image.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a relative path as absolute path.

Comment: Can you add the link to  "BiblePlus" package?